# Organize Windows file paths into folders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, windows

I am going to have a HUGE amount of windows file "URLs" in a json string like this:

```
{"C:\\Users\\Tyler\Desktop\\File1.jpg','C:\\Users\\Tyler\\Desktop\\Folder1\\File2.png"}
```

and so on and so forth...
I need these files to be organized in a sort of Windows explorer type situation on a website, so I need to to be organized to something like this:

```
{"C:":[{"Users":[{"Tyler":[{"Desktop":[{"File1.jpg","Folder1":[{"File2.png"}]}]}]}]}]}
```

I need this to be done in client side javascript, and jquery would also work.
Thanks.

Comment: First code sample is not a valid JSON and second is not a valid JS. Would You please update the question with valid examples?

Comment: Ok, that should be correct...

Comment: what is your question? do you want someone to write code for you and to solve your task or what?

Comment: @Farside Kind of... I want to know how to do a split / type thing but with multiple layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably would not like to mix files and folders in one object. I would suggest the following output structure:

```
{"C:":{"Users":{"Tyler":{"Desktop":{"__files__":["File1.jpg"],
"Folder1":{"__files__":["File2.png"]}}}}}}
```

In order to get desired output, You might go through these steps:

1. parse json string into array of paths
2. process each path in a loop

   1. split path into chunks
   2. strip last chunk and save it for later
   3. put remaining chunks one into another
   4. create `__files__` array at the last level
   5. put previously saved filename into it

The only tricky part may be step `2.3` so I'll provide a sample code:

```
var result = {};
var parts = ['C:', 'Users', 'Tyler'];

var root = result;
while (parts.length) {
    const part = parts.shift();
    root[part] = root[part] || {};
    root = root[part];
}
```

Comment: The sample code seems to return nothing for me..

Comment: Did you check `result` var?

Comment: Now it works, thank you :)